# Xamarin.Android : The connection to Google Play services was lost due to service disconnection

Tags: firebase-authentication, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to test an Xamarin.Android App on both Emulators and Physical Device.
I am using Firebase to try and register users or login with already existing users.

On either of emulator and physical device. I get the response failure message:

The connection to Google Play services was lost due to service disconnection.

Here is the full error received.

```
{Android.Gms.Common.Apis.ApiException: 8: The connection to Google Play services was lost
  --- End of managed Android.Gms.Common.Apis.ApiException stack trace ---
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: The connection to Google Play services was lost
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaab.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:32)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaab.zaag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zabf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:49)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnectionSuspended(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:44)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zag.onConnectionSuspended(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:40)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:8)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
}


void RegisterUser(string name, string phone, string email, string password)
        {
            taskCompletionListener.Success += TaskCompletionListener_Success;
            taskCompletionListener.Failure += TaskCompletionListener_Failure;

            try
            {
                if (mAuth != null)
                {
                    mAuth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                         .AddOnSuccessListener(this, taskCompletionListener)
                         .AddOnFailureListener(this, taskCompletionListener);
                }
          

             
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                
            }
            
            
        }
```

Any  help regarding this issue?

Comment: Could you please post the full error log about this problem?

Comment: please check the edit on the initial post.

Comment: You  can recheck if you have set up Firebase Cloud Messaging correctly. For more ,check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging .